# 2 values in 2 objects that are equal but still calculate as not equal when compared

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have 2 arrays of objects
The structure of the objects is exactly the same, there is a key, a timestamp, and some other stuff

```
arr1 = [{key: 2, timestamp:2020-07-07T02:00:00.000Z},other stuff:....}...]
arr2 = [{key: 7, timestamp:2020-07-07T02:00:00.000Z},other stuff:....}...]
```

arr1 tracks things by the hour so each timestamp is an hourly one
arr2 tracks things every 15 mins so there are timestamps in there that are like `2020-07-07T02:45:00.000Z`

What im trying to do is find were the timestamps match in both arrays
Im looping through 1 array then passing in the timestamp to search for it in the other

Problem is its not finding a matching value even though I know its there

```
arr1.map(function (e) {
        console.log(e.timestamp, arr2[3].timestamp, e.timestamp == arr2[3].timestamp )
      });
```

So the above code goes through all of the timestamp values in arr1 and then console logs them, plus a specific value that I know is in arr1 from arr2, I then console log a comparison

What the console log prints is the following

```
2020-07-07T02:00:00.000Z 2020-07-07T02:00:00.000Z false
```

That `false` should be `true` shouldn't it????

NB: Ive tried with `==` and `===` but both produce `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare the timestamp like that, because timestamp is object.

```js
new Date('2020-07-07T02:00:00.000Z') == new Date('2020-07-07T02:00:00.000Z')

// false
```

Let's try
(e.timestamp - arr2[3].timestamp) == 0)

```js
arr1.map(function (e) {
    console.log(e.timestamp, arr2[3].timestamp, (e.timestamp - arr2[3].timestamp) == 0);
});
```